# Massive slowdown after doing an ALTER to change index from int to bigint, with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, amazon-rds

I have a table like this:

```
create table trades (
    instrument varchar(20)      not null,
    ts         timestamp        not null,
    price      double precision not null,
    quantity   double precision not null,
    direction  integer          not null,
    id         serial
        constraint trades_pkey
            primary key );
```

I wanted to move the id to bigint, so I did:

> ALTER TABLE trades ALTER id TYPE BIGSERIAL;

then, after, I did:

> ALTER SEQUENCE trades_id_seq AS BIGINT;

and now, pretty much any large query, using the id in the WHERE expression, will be so slow it will timeout.

The database is AWS RDS Postgres.

Could it be a problem with the index itself?

---

Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)  SELECT id, instrument, ts, price, quantity, direction FROM binance_trades
WHERE id >= 119655532
ORDER BY ts
LIMIT 50;
```

and output:

> 50 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 1 m 4 s 605 ms (execution: 1 m 4 s 353 ms, fetching: 252 ms)

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..9.86 rows=50 width=44) (actual time=86743.860..86743.878 rows=50 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=20199328 read=1312119 dirtied=111632 written=109974
  I/O Timings: read=40693.524 write=335.051
  ->  Index Scan using idx_extrades_ts on binance_trades  (cost=0.57..8015921.79 rows=43144801 width=44) (actual time=86743.858..86743.871 rows=50 loops=1)
        Filter: (id >= 119655532)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 119654350
        Buffers: shared hit=20199328 read=1312119 dirtied=111632 written=109974
        I/O Timings: read=40693.524 write=335.051
Planning Time: 0.088 ms
Execution Time: 86743.902 ms
```

The activity on AWS:

[image]

it's a 2 cores, 8gb ARM server. Before I did the alter, the same request was < 1 sec.
now, small requests are slow and long ones will timeout.

Comment: I've added details. I don't have the fast case anymore since I've altered the db I'm using (I can lose the data in it since it's for debugging, but I'd prefer not since it's a collection of a week)

Comment: Ok, but you didn't add the output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe fixed

Answer (score 0):

You should try to `ANALYZE` the table and see if that works.

The problem is that PostgreSQL uses an index to support the `ORDER BY`, but not the `WHERE` condition.

To force PostgreSQL to *not* use that index, use

```
ORDER BY ts + INTERVAL '0 seconds';
```

Comment: this still gives me an extremely slow result: execution: 49 s 732 ms, fetching: 55 ms; what I do not understand is that the problem happened when I moved the id to a bigint; I will try right now to delete the id and re-create it with an int just to see if it goes back to how it was before.

Comment: I just moved the id back to int, and the same query is now taking 22secs which is still not right, but much faster. What is odd is that the other tables in the same db are performing very well

Comment: @Thomas  Did you try doing an ANALYZE on the table (or VACUUM ANALYZE)?  The ALTER will clear the stats for that column.  Not having stats will lead to bad plans.

Comment: let me do that right now.

Comment: ANALYZE didn't help, however the universal solution worked: reboot! that's very odd since it's managed by AWS. No matter what I did, this table was insanely slow; I wish I would have been able to understand what happened. At the same time, I saw that AWS had some issue with disk space when I grew the index to big int, it was supposed to autoscale but it somehow didn't so I assume this had some relation.